# Qliksense: making column height dynamic rather than static

Tags: qliksense

In my dataset, there is a `STUFF()` function that is combining multiple values into one string separated by a comma. The problem is that unless I adjust the row height, values are getting cut out. So here's what it looks like without any change on my part:

[image]

But once I adjust the row height, I can get them to show up no problem:

[image]

So the question is, how can I get all the data to show up without having to maximize the cell sizes for every single row? Because some rows have no values at all, or just one, and it looks just awful having every single cell be so needlessly big.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is any way to dynamically influence the row size of table cells, unfortunately. What you could do, though, is simply separate those Prescribers into separate rows using something like this:

```
[NewTable]:
Load
    [RowID]
  , SubField([Prescribers], Chr(10)) as [Prescriber]
Resident [OldTable];
```

I guess the downside of this is that your `[Total Orders Shipped]` measure would then be associated to each Prescriber as a total for the group rather than showing the individual contribution of each Prescriber but I guess as long as that is communicated in the dashboard, it could still be useful.

[image: Screenshot of Qlik Sense table]